# How do I map extensions in SublimeText (Is there a way I can map Sublime Text to treat mjs as js)

Tags: sublime-text-3, node.js

I am currently working with nodejs modules and, despite being just js files, it uses the mjs extension when I declare `--experimental-modules`. Is there a way I can map Sublime Text to treat mjs as js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is there a way I can map Sublime Text to treat mjs as js?

See the following answer from StackOverflow:

> In the current version of Sublime Text 2 (Build: 2139), you can set
>   the syntax for all files of a certain file extension using an option
>   in the menu bar. Open a file with the extension you want to set a
>   default for and navigate through the following menus: `View -> Syntax
>   -> Open all with current extension as... ->[your syntax choice]`.
>
> **Updated 2012-06-28:** Recent builds of Sublime Text 2 (at least since Build 2181) have allowed the syntax to be set by clicking the
>   current syntax type in the lower right corner of the window. This will
>   open the syntax selection menu with the option to `Open all with
>   current extension as...` at the top of the menu.
>
> **Updated 2016-04-19:** As of now, this also works for Sublime Text 3.

Source [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014142/3536342), answer by [Colin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017768/colin-r)